# Common SMART values for all vendors?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

Is there a list of SMART values that all HDD/SSD vendors have in common ? Or just every vendor implements its own list of SMART values ? Our application might handle HDD or SSD.

Comment: What have you you researched so far?

Comment: I'm not going to post a link-only answer, so here is wikipedia link: [S.M.A.R.T. - Lack of common interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Lack_of_common_interpretation)

Comment: Really ? Thanks for the wikipedia Link!! Like you think I post but I don't search or that link contains what I need. We need to implement SMART values in an application but our consideration is that each vendor implements its own values.

Comment: You're welcome. If you ask a vague question, you'll get a vague answer. You should've stated that you're developing app. and you need a DB of SMART attributes. See my answer about where to get one.

Answer (score 1):

Your updated question shines light on your original intent. There is no "approved" list of S.M.A.R.T. attributes and their per-vendor interpretation. But for the starters I advise you to look at the [Smartmontools Database](http://sourceforge.net/p/smartmontools/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/smartmontools/drivedb.h).

Answer (score 0):

Current/worst/threshold values are vendor-specific, but since the only vendors now are WD and Seagate, it should not be hard to compare them. Just put two drives together, open HDTune (or other smart enough utility) and goto Health.

What is actually relevant is usually the data field and the C/W values that approach a threshold; it is less relevant if the C/W values are 200 or 100 (commonly used).

SSDs are another story, but the same applies: values are vendor-specific.

Comment: WD, Seagate, Intel, Kingston, Samsung, etc. Aren't they all HDD/SSD vendors ?

Comment: No. SSDs are not HDDs. As I said, WD and SG. The rest have been assimilated (like hitachi, fujitsu, samsung).

Comment: What you are saying they are the main vendors and to compare with their two implementations ?

Comment: And what about Toshiba ?

Comment: Yes. SG uses 100-based values while WD uses 200-based values for the majority of the C/W.

Comment: Toshiba is the last survivor except the two (there are still drives out there), but it will be out of the HDD market totally quite soon , that's why they assimilated OCZ.